# getting value from foo into bar when defining object?

Tags: javascript, object

Ok I have a simple test object here:

```
var test = {

    foo: "dude",
    bar: "ok " + foo

}
```

as you can see, I want to use foo inside bar here, but its undefined.

i have also tried

```
   bar: "ok " + test.foo
```

but test is also undefined, which kinda makes sense because im not done defining it when i do that...

well i know i can do this

```
var test = {

    foo: "dude"

}

test.bar = "ok " + test.foo
```

but Its not really that pretty, that i have to define it "outside" the test object.

Is it possible to do what i want? or is the last way the only way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn it into method :

```
bar: function() { return "ok " + this.foo ;}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8xqGL/

Comment: The change from scalar to function notwithstanding, this results in different behavior than the original code: now `bar` gets live-updated with the changes in `foo`. That may not be desirable.

Comment: @Jon Exactly , but we definitely can assume that it is desirable!

Comment: @Cherniv what makes you so absolutely sure it is desired?

Comment: @JanDvorak primary data given us by OP

Comment: @Cherniv: I respectfully disagree -- assuming without knowledge is called making a wild guess and I 'm against it. At the very least, when changing the semantics of the original code the difference should be made very explicit in order to avoid surprises.

Comment: @Jon please agree with me that in many points in life we don't have enough knowledge but we still make decisions. And note that you have changed the semantics of the original code too :)

Comment: @Cherniv: I 'm not sure what you are trying to say at all, but please note the "at the very least" suggestion above. I also do not see how I changed the semantics.

Comment: okay, thx guys... I can only say this does excatly what i want. I have tested it no matter what i do (changing value of foo etc etc) bar always has the value that i expect and want. So thank you. Super fast response as always. :-) - And yes i wanted it live-updated with the changes in foo :)

Comment: @Jon no matter what, you're very nice companion for conversation. Accidentally my "wild guess" was not so wrong.. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that we don't get to change the structure of the code then you have to define something outside the `test` object. But IMHO it would be better to do it like this:

```
var foo = "dude";

var test = {
    foo: foo,
    bar: "ok " + foo
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "no, there is no other way doing what you want". But, you might want to consider using a closure instead.

```
var test = (function () {

    var foo, bar;

    foo = "dude";
    bar = "ok " + foo;

    return {
        foo: foo,
        bar: bar
    }

}());
```